# Import double side images (Two images same product) import using magmi

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magmi

How can i import double side image of same product using `MAGMI`

my excel format not support ,

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?